# Curvature of a parallel surface

Tags: differential-geometry

I have found a couple of questions that deal with the basic concepts, I am asking about, but nothing that is quite the same as my question.  So ....

This is a question from an MIT OpenCourseWare site, if you're wondering.

Let $f(s,t)$ be a surface patch in $\mathbb{R}^3$.  Let $\nu$ be the Guass normal of $f$ and $\epsilon$ a real constant.  Now define a second patch $\tilde{f}(s,t) = f(s,t)+\epsilon\nu(s,t)$  Show that the two principle curvatures of $f$ and $\tilde{f}$, are related by $\tilde{\lambda}_i = \lambda/(1-\epsilon \lambda_i)$.  Ass ume \epsilon is as small as needed for the argument.

"Small as needed" I take to mean small enough to avoid a singularity.

Anyway, after some brute force calculating, I was able to show $\tilde{\nu}=\nu$.  Then, trying to get the equation for the $\tilde{\lambda}$, I start with

$\det(H-\lambda G) = 0$,

do a bunch of substituting and wind up with

$\det (\tilde{H}_{ij}(1-2\epsilon\lambda)-\lambda\tilde{G}_{ij}+\epsilon(1-\epsilon\lambda)\partial_i\nu\partial_j\nu)=0$

Not quite what I want.  Did I go off the rail somewhere, or is there something helpful to be done with that last term?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Algebraically you are subtracting away length $\epsilon$ from the length of normal vector to  change its reciprocal scalar curvature.

$ 1/\tilde{\lambda}_i = 1/ {\lambda} - \epsilon  \rightarrow \tilde{\lambda}_i = \lambda/(1-\epsilon \lambda_i).$

Comment: Understood, thanks.  The thing is I haven't been able to get this result by going through the mchinery of differential geometry.

Comment: @bob.sacamento: It is instructive to go through exercises relating to change in (H,K) curvature of such parallel Bertrand surfaces... algebraically. Again, do not get ready with the DG machinery.